# Is there a way to draw a graph by points from a Numpy array in manim?

Tags: python, manim

There are two arrays of x and y coordinates. I created NumberPlane() axes, but I can't figure out how to plot points on a plane using array values in manim (arrays are large, so entering values manually is not an option either). Subsequently, I want to interpolate them using smooth curves, but I found a way to perform only linear interpolation of plot_line_graph, it does not suit me. Does anyone know how to solve these problems and is there a way at all?

P. S. Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to do this with **for**, but it doesn't work out. The code fragment is attached:

```
class OrbitalTrajectoryAnimation(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        axes = Axes().add_coordinates()
        dots_axes = np.zeros((163, 1))
        for k in range(0, 163):
            dots_axes[k] = Dot(axes.coords_to_point(x[k], y[k]), color=GREEN)
        plane = NumberPlane()
        self.add(plane, axes, dots_axes)
```

Comment: standard rule: if you have `list` or `array` then use `for`-loop.

Comment: BTW: if you have values in separated lists then you can use `zip()` to create pairs `for x,y in zip(all_x, all_y):`

Comment: better show minimal working code with example data in code, and expected result. This way we can simply copy code and test it.

Comment: for interpolation you may need to use other modules. Using Google `python interpolate function` I found [scipy.interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate.html)

Answer (score 1):

> P. S. Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to do this with for, but it doesn't work out.

Try initializing your list:

```
dots_axes = [None]*163
```

And use the * operator to pass the dots individually:

```
self.add(plane, axes, *dots_axes)
```